# Add month year separately from file info

Tags: c#

How can I add month and year separately from file info to my list `fiList` as variables ?

```
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();

foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
{
    fiList.Add(fi);
}
```

Comment: create a new type (class say) which have necessary to you fields.

Comment: You have a single list, so how do you want to separate it? Do you want a `List<List<FileInfo>>>` where each year-month has it's own list?

Comment: Would you like to be more specific?

Comment: Do you mean `fi.CreationTime.Month` and `fi.CreationTime.Year`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myList = info.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime)
    .Select(fi => new { FileInfo = fi, Year = fi.CreationTime.Year })
    .ToArray();
```

This returns an array of an anonymous type containing the properties `FileInfo` and `Year`. To ensure learning success, adding a property `Month` is left as an exercise for the reader.